# Remove numbers that contains 8-10 digits at different places in a line

Tags: regex

I have a list of different items. Some of them have 8-10 digits in front of the name, some others have these 8-10 digits behind the name and some others again don't have these numbers in the name.

I have two expressions that I use to remove these digits, but I can not manage to combine them with | (or). They work each for themselves, but if I use the first expression first, then the second expression, I don't get the result I want to have.

I use these to expressions for now:

```
(?<=[\d]{8,10}) (.*)
.*?(?=[\d]{8,10})
```

But if I use them both (first one and then the other), then some of the lines become totally empty.

How can I combine these to to do what I want, or if it's better, write a new expression that does what I want to do :)

List is like this:

```
12345678 Book
12345678 Book
Book 12345678
Book 12345678
Cabinet 120x30x145
```

Want this result:

```
Book
Book
Book
Book
Cabinet 120x30x145
```

Comment: What regex flavor are you using (i.e. which tool) and how do you apply it? Just getting a regex to match does not remove text, so please make a [mcve] to demonstrate.

Comment: Why not replace `\b\d{8,10}\b` with nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the following.
Check if there are 8 numbers in the beginning of the string, or at the end of it and remove them.

[`(^\d{8,10}\s*|\s*\d{8,10}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/tattx3/1)

It gives the wanted behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only matching **everything but a number** containing
8-10 digits + adjacent spaces, use a regex to **substitute**
such a number (also + adjacent spaces) with an **empty string**.

To match, use the following regex:

```
*\d{8,10} *
```

That is:

- `*` - a space and an asterix - a sequence of spaces (may be empty),
- `\d{8,10}` - a sequence of 8 to 10 digits,
- `*` - another sequence of spaces (may be empty).

The replacement string is (as I said) empty. Of course, you should use
`g` (global) option.

Note that you can not use `\s` instead of the space, as `\s` matches also
`CR` and `LF` and we don't want this.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/1hsGzT/1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\b` [meta sequence boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html):

> ```
> /\b[0-9\s]{8,10}\b/g;
> ```

```js
var str = `12345678 Book
12345678 Book
Book 12345678
Book 12345678
Cabinet 120x30x145`;

var rgx = /\b[0-9\s]{8,10}\b/g;

var res = str.replace(rgx, `\n`)

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This will remove `123   456`